# Django many-to-many relationship doesn't return set object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I've the following User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Which has a ManyToMany relationship with a Room

```
class Room(Base):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')
```

When I run the following query,

```
rooms = user.room_set.all()
```

I get this error,

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'room_set'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have user attribute in Room model !

Use this in room class :

```
 users= models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Also see [django doc examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) .

Comment: I've to say this is the simplest answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's just because you have changed the **related_name** to `users`

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')
```

Instead of `rooms = user.room_set.all()` try `rooms = user.users.all()`.

Note that it's more convenient to name the **related_name** with the plural of the `class_name`, so you would have:

```
class Room(models.Model)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='rooms')
```

If you want to use the one of django `classname_set`; Just remove `related_name`, so `user.room_set.all` will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Room(Model.models):
    user = models.ForignKey (User,ONCASCADE  = models.delete)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='users')
```